# Prove that for a quadratic form $Q(x) = x^TAx$, $A$ is symmetric.

Tags: linear-algebra

We want to show that $A=A^T$. Any matrix $A$ may be written as a sum of its symmetric and skew symmetric parts: $A = \frac{A+A^T}{2} + \frac{A-A^T}{2}$. Upon substitution, we obtain $Q(x) = x^T (\frac{A+A^T}{2} + \frac{A-A^T}{2}) x$. How am I supposed to show from here that $A-A^T = 0$?

Answer (score 3):

It's not true: $x^T A x$ is a quadratic form for any matrix $A$, symmetric or not.  The point is that you can **choose** it to be symmetric, since $A$ and $(A + A^T)/2$ produce the same quadratic form.